# Android: Drawing multiple paths

Tags: android, path, android-canvas

I'm trying to develop a simple "draw-on-touch" and I want to draw the different paths that the user places in an onTouch listener.
I've got a simple problem. When I draw the paths I obtain a single path drawn in the points of the last onTouch entry.
I think the paths are all drawn over the last path because I use a Paint with a 150 alpha and it looks more solid in the second and succesive onTouch entries.

How could I solve that? Thanks!

```
public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener {


List<List<Point>> paths = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Paint paintLine = new Paint();
Paint paintCircle = new Paint();

public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    paintLine = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintLine.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paintLine.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paintLine.setAlpha(150);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    List<Point> pointsList;
    List<Path> pathList = new ArrayList<Path>();
    Point point = new Point();

    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
        pointsList = paths.get(i);

        path.reset();
        boolean first = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < points.size(); j+=2 ) {
            point = pointsList.get(j);

            if (first) {
                first = false;
                path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
            } else if (j < pointsList.size() - 1 ) {
                Point nextPoint = pointsList.get(j+1);
                path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
            } else {
                path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }

        }

        pathList.add(path);
    }

    for (Path pathDraw : pathList) {
        canvas.drawPath(pathDraw, paintLine);
    }

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, final MotionEvent event) {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = event.getX();
    point.y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // DO SOMETHING
        points.clear();
        points.add(point);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        points.add(point);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        points.add(point);
        paths.add(points);
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing paths constructed with the points in the `points` list **repeatedly**.

Note that `invalidate()` call in `onTouch`, each of this call will trigger a redraw event, which causes `onDraw` to be called, everything looks fine at this point. The problem is you only did `points.clear()` on `ACTION_DOWN` event, but you also **should have** cleared them on `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP` events. Instead, you keep all the points collected previously and draw the paths constructed with all those points in `onDraw`. So you are effectively drawing repeatedly some of the paths constructed with the points collected previously.

Note in a drag motion, there will be **1 ACTION_DOWN**, **N ACTION_MOVE**, **0 or 1 ACTION_UP** events.

Comment: Thanks now I understood the way that Path runs. I don't need to create multiple paths I can do everything with only one. The code was modified and I don't need any 'points.clear()' all that i have to do is to generate the 'Path' directly in the 'onTouch()' method using 'moveTo' into the 'ACTION_DOWN', 'lineTo' in the 'ACTION_MOVE' and 'lineTo' int the 'ACTION_UP'. Then in the 'onDraw' method all that I need is to draw the only path that I've got.